# verify signature from google pay?

Tags: php, android

I use openssl_verify in php to verify signature from my app

```
<?php
// $data and $signature are assumed to contain the data and the signature

// fetch public key from certificate and ready it
$pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public("file://src/openssl-0.9.6/demos/sign/cert.pem");

// state whether signature is okay or not
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $pubkeyid);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "good";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "bad";
} else {
    echo "ugly, error checking signature";
}
// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
?>
```

my php build-in function require $pubkeyid as file pem but google send me a public key as String. They said `Note:To find the public key portion of this key pair, open your application's details in the Developer Console, then click on Services & APIs, and look at the field titled Your License Key for This Application.`

My question is how to create file cert.pem from publickey String (public key which google sent me)
Thank you so much !

Comment: copy and paste into text file, save as `cert.pem`?

Comment: @RamRaider it not work, it said "penssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key"